# Selecting multiple attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute

I have a MS excel table with several thousand numbers that I need to select out of a single shapefile field with 20,000 numbers.
How do I build a sql statement in select by attributes to do this?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Add the excel table to the map and join to the shapefile. Select the rows where there is a match

Comment: Maybe time to use a databse such as PostgreSQL/PostGIS to do this... excel and shapefiles weren't really meant to do this... though I'm sure someone will post something, it will not be pretty...